# How to MAX() on any column type at SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view with many columns and a query builder that will eventually add a `MAX` statement on the query. Problem is, when the column type is BIT I cannot use `MAX` on it, so I need to check type before. I cannot check the data type of the column during the query builder, so I need a SQL solution that works fine for any data type.

Here is an example (the `SELECT` within the `CTE` represents a `VIEW` which can have any type of data on `mycol`, for this first example I'm simulating a `BIT`. The `MAX` portion is where I need to work on):

**ORIGINAL**

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(1 as BIT) as mycol
)
SELECT
    MAX(mycol) as mycol_max
FROM cte
```

I got this error:

> Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.

**CASTING**

If I do the following it will work:

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS
(
     SELECT CAST(1 as BIT) as mycol
)
SELECT
    MAX(CAST(mycol as INT)) as mycol_max
FROM cte
```

However, if `mycol` is a string (SELECT 'test' as mycol), I got this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int.

So, I tried to check type using some different approaches:

**ISNUMERIC()**

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS
(
     SELECT 'test' as mycol
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE 
           WHEN 1 = ISNUMERIC(mycol) 
              THEN CAST(mycol AS INT) 
              ELSE mycol 
        END) AS mycol_max
FROM cte
```

**NOT LIKE %[^0-9]%**

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS
(
     SELECT 'test' as mycol
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE 
           WHEN "mycol" NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
              THEN CAST(mycol AS INT) 
              ELSE mycol 
        END) AS mycol_max
FROM cte;
```

**TRY_PARSE**

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS 
(
     SELECT 'test' as mycol
)
SELECT
    MAX(CASE 
           WHEN TRY_PARSE(mycol AS INT) IS NOT NULL 
              THEN CAST(mycol AS INT) 
           ELSE mycol 
        END) AS mycol_max
FROM cte
```

All of these returned the error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int.

Also, if `mycol` is an integer:

```
WITH cte (mycol) AS
(
     SELECT 1 as mycol
)
...
```

I got

> Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of parse function.

So, all I need is to allow anything into the `MAX()` statement. I tried checking and converting, but didn't get any satisfactory solution. How can I do it?

Thanks

Using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Why are you trying to apply the same logic to an `bit`, `int`,`varchar` etc? They're all different data types; treat them appropriately. It would be like expecting a `varchar` to behave the same way an an `int` with the `+` operator. If `11+22=33` what does `'aa'+'bb'` equal? It should be `'aabb'` not `'cc'`. Why? Because a `varchar` is not an `int`; and a `bit` is not a `int` (or even a numerical data type).

Comment: Iam trying to apply the same logic because i need something generic, as at the moment of the query builder (PHP) i don't know the column type. MAX works fine to everything except BIT, but converting BIT to INT is not working. Why none of the solutuions above work? I'm just casting if the column contains a number, but the error happens on the ELSE, which don't have any convertion.

Comment: Then find out th data types. Applying `MAX`  to a `bit` doesnt even make sense anyway. With a bit, `1` isn't greater (or less than) `0`, they aren't numbers; they're more like a Boolean value. Is `TRUE >FALSE`?  Does it make sense for it to be? No. If anything, I'd say for a `bit` the "MAX" value is the most common value; which is not what `MAX` does.

Comment: But you can't perform the same logic to every column, as all the data types are different. Take the values 05122019 and 17012017. For an `int` the "max" is 17012017, as it is for a `varchar`, but for a `date` it's 05122019.  What about the values 0123 and 5. For an `int` 0123 is greater, for a `varchar` it's 5. Data types all act differently and so should your code. The way to fix the "problem" is to not try to treat everything the same; because it isn't. What you have here is a classic example of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

BIT Won't behave as int so MAX won't really work unless you just choose max LEN which is still not optimal. You might try ORDER BY DESC but I doubt it will help. You might as well add another column that will specify what exactly MAX you're looking for.

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(1 as BIT) as mycol
FROM TB1
ORDER BY mycol DESC
```